# After Log out from my app, if i press back button, i can see the previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I have embedded the no-cache code in application_controller. But, it works only in certain cases. Is there any other solution to this problem? how does Facebook and Gmail manage to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have no idea how your authentication has been implemented.  You have to provide more details / code.

Comment: From looking at your code I think it's best to pick up a book and start all over.  Your source code is riddled with strange files which seem to be the result of you executing ( rails related ) commands the wrong way.  It's hard for me to pinpoint the exact issue by looking at the source code, but I can tell you, that you need to study Ruby and the Rails framework a bit more before diving in.  Don't give up.  Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser cacheing pages while you are requesting any page. You need to prevent browser to cache. So you can do it like this.

In your application_controller:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster
def set_cache_buster
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

All the credit goes to this url http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/

Comment: I have written this code in my application_controller.rb...but it's not working for all pages...is there any other alternate method like refreshing when i press back button?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can do it like this. document.onHistoryGo = function() { location.reload(); return false; }